# jenkins jacoco plugin cannot use .. and . to match class folder

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, jacoco

When I use `..` or `.` relative-like path to match folders(some class and source folders)

jacoco plugin says:

> Overall coverage: class: 0, method: 0, line: 0, branch: 0, instruction: 0

but when I copy the folder to my project and of course I use no `..` and `.`

it can match the folder correctly what I need.

jacoco plugin says:

> Overall coverage: class: 100, method: 50, line: 38, branch: 33, instruction: 40

another experiment: I use absolute path(windows os) to match, and it doesn't work either.

ps: I have already generated the jacoco.exec file,all I need to do is tell jacoco plugin where the class and source files are.

and these files are located in another project, so I have to use `..` to switch project

Comment: Since this seem to solely relate to Jenkins Plugin and not to JaCoCo library itself: have you tried to reach Jenkins Plugin developers via their mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jenkins-jacoco-plugin-mailing-list ?

Comment: thanks, i agree with you and i will contact them. :)